# Repeat a HTTP service in Angular 5 for an array of objects

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

My intent is to show an ngx-bootstrap progress bar for items in an array for which a Rest service has been called. The third party backend does not accept an array of objects but only a post request with x-www-form-urlencoded content-type.

I have already created the data service and wish to iterate over the items in the array and call the service for each of them one by one. Simultaneously updating the progress bar.

Array of objects: `cars: IProject[] = [];`

Component constructor with service: `

```
constructor(private eventProjectService: EventProjectService) {

}
```

`

Save function:

```
save() {
    this.max = this.cars.length;
    this.processedCountForProgressBar = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.max; i++) {
        processedCountForProgressBar++;
        this.eventProjectService.saveProject().subscribe((data) => {
            // handle success/error msgs  
        });
    }
}
```

Suggest me a way to achieve this.

Comment: Your implemntation looks ok, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @ritaj Currently the for loop fires all the requests at one go and I want to send second request only after first request has sent a response i.e. handle the async flow.

Comment: Do requests depend on each other? If not, why would  you want to send them one after another, and not in parallel?

Comment: Just to fill the progress bar status gradually and no the requests are not dependent on each other.

Comment: Why you want to  send multiple request  Instead of Http Service you could use HttpClient it provides you ability to listen to progress events.

Answer (score 0):

You should just move your `processedCountForProgressBar` counter increase to request handler.

```
save() {
    this.max = this.cars.length;
    this.processedCountForProgressBar = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.max; i++) {
        this.eventProjectService.saveProject().subscribe((data) => {
            processedCountForProgressBar++;
            // handle success
        });
    }
}
```

That way, the counter will increase only after you receive the request response.

Also, depending on what you want to do with errored requests, you could also handle errors like so:

```
this.eventProjectService.saveProject().subscribe(
        (data) => {
            processedCountForProgressBar++;
            // handle success
        },
        (error) => processedCountForProgressBar++;
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally achieved desired functionality using recursion:

```
Upload() {
  this.max = this.cars.length;
  this.processedCountForProgressBar  = 0;

  if (this.max > 0) {
    this.spinnerService.show();
    this.showProgressBar = true;
    this.saveProject(0);
  } else {
    this.showProgressBar = false;
  }
}

saveProject(position: number) {
  if (position < this.cars.length) {
    const project: IProject = this.cars[position];
    // call import service
    this.eventProjectService.importProject(
     // API params
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      this.processedCountForProgressBar ++;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      // handle success/error
      this.saveProject(this.processedCountForProgressBar );
    });
  } else {
    this.spinnerService.hide();    
    // return from recurssion
    return;
  }
}
```